# How can I skip query if clause is null in MyBatis?

Tags: java, mybatis

The results of select query appear as below.
The total column will contain the sum of each row.

| day_1 | day_2 | day_3 | total |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| [NULL] | 6 | [NULL] | 6 |
| [NULL] | [NULL] | [NULL] | 0 |

To find the total value, I used the function below.

```
(
  <foreach item="item" collection="dayList" open="" separator=" + " close="">
            COALESCE(day_${item}, 0)
  </foreach>
) AS total
```

The result I want is as shown below.
If all items in a row are NULL, I want the NULL value to appear.

| day_1 | day_2 | day_3 | total |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| [NULL] | 6 | [NULL] | 6 |
| [NULL] | [NULL] | [NULL] | [NULL] |

I think if do this 
I expected that

```
    (
      <foreach item="item" collection="dayList" open="" separator=" + " close="">
     <if test="#{'hour_' + item} != null">
        hour_${item}
     </if>
      </foreach>
    ) AS total
```

the result would only add things that are not null.

Comment: You may have to add a NULL check i.e. `... case when coalesce(day_1, day_2, day_3) then coalesce(day_1, 0) + coalesce(day_2, 0) + coalesce(day_3, 0) else null end as total`.
It might be better to calculate `total` in Java code. BTW, it's not possible to check column values in `<if>` because `<if>` conditions are evaluated before executing the query.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
(
  <foreach item="item" collection="dayList" open="" separator=" + " close="">
            COALESCE(day_${item}, null)
  </foreach>
) AS total
```

Comment: If I do that, won't a null value come out when null + 6?